# Question about continuity and absolute value

Tags: continuity, absolute-value

If $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$, ..., $f_n(x)$, are continuous functions, then
$$
\sum_{\textrm{some }i} |f_i(x)| + \prod_{\textrm{some }i} |f_i(x)| 
$$
is continue? If a such theorem exists, it would be useful in finding maxima and minima of some functions.

Comment: Sum, product, and composition of continuous functions are continuous. This means that that thing is continuous.

Comment: Thanks you have been useful to me